# Problem with nontypical rounding in python

Tags: python, math, rounding

I'm testing a system where is specific rounding - last number is always rounded up

e.g.

- `123,459` should yield `123,46`
- `99,9911` should yield `100,00`

How can I implement it in python?

**EDIT**

The most important thing - those numbers are prices

Comment: in your seconds example the last digit isn't rounded up. You basically just reducing the precision to 2 digits, which is something entirely different. Also, are you using , as the decimal point? (I know some countries use that) if so please change it to . because most SO users will find it confusing.

Comment: Which is the "last number", and why shouldn't the second example be `99,991`?

Comment: Are you using `decimal`? If not why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import math
def myRounding(x):
   return math.ceil(x*100) / 100.0
```

Note that due to floating point not being able to express all decimal fractions, some results won't be able to be expressed in floating point numbers. If this is an issue, calculate in fixed-point numbers (i.e. 1.23 is represented by `123`, with a fixed factor of `0.01`), or use [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

> ***[...] last number is always rounded up.***

This rounds to `n-1` decimals where `n` represents the number of digits after the decimal point.

```
def roundupLast(x):
    return round(x, len(str(x).split(".")[-1]) - 1)


print(roundupLast(123.459))  # 123.46
print(roundupLast(99.9911))  # 99.991
print(roundupLast(99.9916))  # 99.992
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using formatter

```
NSNumber *Numero = 99.99
NSNumberFormatter *Formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
[Formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];     

//Formatter ROUNDING MODE
[Formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

[Formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[Formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

result = [Formatter stringFromNumber:Numero];
[Formatter release];
```

Comment: This is Objective C; the question is about Python.